# Launch safari from a Mac application

Tags: macos

How can I launch the Safari browser or the user's default browser pointing it to a specific address from within my Mac application?

I am using Objective-C as the programming language.

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From a shell you can use the `open` command with a URL as a parameter, and that takes care of opening that URL in the default browser.

So you should be able to use `system()` or similar `fork()/exec()` code to do the same.

nb: `open` will also open other sorts of files / URLs, too, so make sure it really is a web URL you're trying to open otherwise you've got a probable security problem.

The Objective C way of doing it appears to be:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:url];
```

where `url` is a pointer to an NSURL object